# Is there a list of Dungeon Defenders Huntress weapons and their special attributes?

Tags: dungeon-defenders

Is there a list somewhere of Huntress weapons, and their special attributes?

For example, I know some guns shoot multiple shots, some pierce, some shoot grenades, some are double-element, some pierce walls/floors, etc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a link for bows: http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Bows

And one for guns: http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Guns

Comment: Very incomplete lists...

Comment: That list is the base for all types of guns because all the other stats are random. Combine that with the prefix list that you get here it will give you a good idea of the type of weapon you are getting. http://dungeondefenders.wikia.com/wiki/Armor